# How to use Magento 2 as a dynamic controller ? like used in CodeIgniter or Laravel?

Tags: magento2

I want to create some public pages with dynamic URL,
if I write code like
`execute($id){}`
`abc.com/plugin/controller/action/some_id`

How to possible this things in M2?

Answer (score 1):

As per the provided URL

`abc.com/plugin/controller/action/some_id`

`some_id` would be the parameter right? you can use it as it is and get it from the $this->request->getParam('some_id') object and render the page.

By default in Magento, you call also use the same URL to render the page with the response and result object.

If you want to use some other dynamic url you can also create a custom router. with di.xml

create file `module-name/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="plugin" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">ABC\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

and then create a controller class wich implements

`\Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface` and with `match()` function in this class to use your own route matching logic.

For more referance, you can refer the https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#custom-routers